# Force Crash FireFox Tab Using JS/firefox:about

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-tab

Like in chrome we can simply force crash a tab by hitting `chrome://crash`  in the address bar like-wise I would like to know if the same could be done for a tab in firefox ?, if yes how do could I achieve that ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

`about:tabcrashed` is a rough equivalent of `chrome://crash`